# How can I pass in a parameter to a Java Processing function?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make a program which creates a ball that is affected by gravity, and I wanted to use Java Processing to show it. How do I call this function and pass in a parameter without calling my other `PApplet` functions?

```
public void draw(Ball ball){
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.draw(ball);
}
```

I use

```
PApplet.main("Main", args);
```

to run

```
public void settings(){
    size(1000, 1000);
}
public void setup(){
    processing = this;
}
public void draw(Ball ball){
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.draw(ball);
}
```

I tried to use

```
PApplet.main("Circle", ball)
```

to call the circle command, and to pass in "ball" as its paramater, but it resulted in the default 100x100 px window.

Also I am new to this, if someone could help me format questions that would be great.

it is [`processing.core.PApplet`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html), `Circle` is just a class I created that contains the y and the x value. In case it matters, I am using IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: yeah it is processing.core.PApplet, Circle is just a class I created that contains the y and the x value.

Comment: Hello, we need your question to have the minimum code required to reproduce your problem on our own computers. It's missing a lot of needed code to understand your problem.

Comment: Documentation says the draw method should have no parameters:

https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#draw--

you'll have to call main with your ball argument and store that in a variable. I need to see your main method to produce a working answer that helps you.

Comment: *yeah it is processing.core.PApplet, Circle is just a class I created ...* Thanks for this. I added it to your question. It’s always best to have everything in one  place, so please do it yourself next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***Circle***
is a keyword for Processing so I would suggest using something like 'Ball' for your class name.  Normally something like the following is how this is handled in Processing.  You would still need code for animation of the ball.  This code is to be run in the Processing editor, which is here:https://processing.org/download  if you don't already have it.  It is possible to run Processing code in IntelliJ but you have to import the core library from the Processing app and it is not as easy to do.

```
Ball b;

class Ball{
  float x, y, diam;
  
  //Constructor
  Ball(float xPos, float yPos, float diameter){
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
    diam = diameter;
  }
  
  void display(){
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    circle(x,y,diam);
  }
}

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  b = new Ball(100,100,40);
}

void draw(){
   b.display();
}
```